# Why am I getting these Silex 404's?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, wamp, silex

Just getting started with Silex and having some issues.

Downloaded the [fat zip file](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/get/silex_fat.zip), unzipped it into `wamp`'s `www` folder. So, here's `C:\wamp\www\fat-silex\web\index.php`:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app->get('/hello', function() {
    return 'Hello!';
});
$app->run();
```

Problem is I'm getting Apache's 404's for `http://localhost/fat-silex/web/hello`, and also for any URL except `localhost/fat-silex/web`, where I'm getting Silex'es 404 (as expected). I guess the requests go directly to Apache, and are not routed by Silex. This looks like the problem could be solved with a `.htaccess` file, so I added this one, suggested in the [official documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /fat-silex
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, it doesn't seem to have *any* effect at all.

Comment: Is your webroot /fat-silex ? or /fat-silex/web?

Comment: @gunnx, assuming webroot means the folder containing `index.php`, webroot is `/fat-silex/web`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your rewrite base should be `/fat-silex/web`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /fat-silex/web
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tested it on my localhost, and it works fine

Comment: thanks a lot for actually taking the time to test the code; that makes a lot of sense, but still fails on my machine. I've set up a [github repo](https://github.com/mihai-rotaru/silex-bootstrap) and I'm working on a Vagrant machine to get to the bottom of this :D

Comment: Seems it should work. Have you checked your apache AllowOverride setting? Maybe your .htaccess get ignored by apache? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: @ChuanMa I tried replacing `AllowOverride None` with `AllowOverride All` ([gist](https://gist.github.com/mihai-rotaru/5203550/revisions)) but no luck. I'm using Ubuntu and the default Apache 2.2 install on a Vagrant precise32 box.

Comment: finally got it - `mod_rewrite` wasn't enabled. I tracked down the issue in the Ubuntu VM - and fixed it with `sudo a2enmod rewrite`, and then noticed that `mod_rewrite` wasn't enabled in my Windows `WAMP` setup. Enabled it (right click Apache Modules -> check `rewrite_module` or from `httpd.conf`), and all is good. Doing `AllowOverride` was needed on Ubuntu, but not on `WAMP`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is your apache conf. If you don't use virtual host you should configure apache to allow htaccess file of your project directory.
On Linux (Ubuntu) : `sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride None
  ...
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/fat-silex/>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: yes, but in this case I was using WAMP and the issue was that `mod_rewrite` wasn't enabled; see [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498419/why-am-i-getting-these-silex-404s/17802778?noredirect=1#comment21984228_15500825)